# Basic rails collection select question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A card can have one of many card_types. There are two models, card and card_type, where card_type is an [id, card_type_desc] pairing.

When you define a new card, you have to pick a card-type from a drop down list.

I have the list rendering correctly with the below collection_select box, but the new card.card_type_id field is NULL. How do you set it to the value from the list?

```
<%= collection_select(:card_type, :id, @card_types, :id, :card_type_desc) %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same problem once. Can you do the following instead f.collection_select(..) (I suppose you have |f| but use whatever you are using for the form) and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, It should be...

```
<%= collection_select(:card, :card_type_id, @card_types, :id, :card_type_desc) %>
```